# Compilation sequence for TexWorks

Tags: luatex, texworks

I have switched from texmaker to TeXworks because LuaLatex does not work properly in texmaker.

In TeXworks there are different options for compiliation, such as LuaLaTex, Bibtex and MakeIndex and the combination of them (LuaLaTeX + Bibtex + MakeIndex). I don't know MakeIndex from texmaker.

What should I run for the right compilation?

By the way, I'm not able to get the citations to work. In TexMaker I have always used 2 x PdfLaTeX + 2 x Bibtex + 2 x PdfLatex.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in calling LuaLaTeX from Texmaker or from TeXworks, both editors will call the same program. They might be configured with different options, but I don't think that should be a problem. The *LuaLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX* option should in theory do all the runs of LuaLaTeX, MakeIndex (if you have an index, which it doesn't sound like you do) and BibTeX necessary so that all references are resolved. You can try that, or you can do LuaLaTeX then BibTeX then twice LuaLaTeX. This should work the same in both editors.

Comment: By the way, the question *What should I run for the right compilation?* is rather open, because it depends on the content of your document. If you can't make things work, then you need to give us more information about your document (i.e. provide a minimal example), and tell us exactly how it fails.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you for your answer. :) What do you mean by index? I have table of contents, list of figures etc. Do I have to run MakeIndex? But MakeIndex throws an error...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Regarding the editors, with TexWorks everything is fine now but with Texmaker only pdflatex works. When I try to run LuaLaTeX a message appears that no log file is found. I have already delete all .aux etc. files (cleaned up everything). This did not help.

Comment: By index I mean [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(publishing)),  the list of (key) words and phrases with page references in a book usually found at the back. As you don't have that, you don't need to run MakeIndex.  The *log file not found* problem is rather common with Texmaker I believe (search the site and you'll find several questions), but I don't know what causes it.